# Quantum Machine Learning added to Data Science?

Tags: discussion

I wanted to propose that quantum machine learning, or quantumAI (see [google](https://plus.google.com/+QuantumAILab/posts) or [quopal](http://quopal.com/) ) should be affiliated to the Data science stackexchange? It is a very recent research area and might grow quickly in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about it, myself. I imagine this is a heavily theoretical area, and the discussion may center on the physics of it rather than any application to practical data science. I suspect therefore most questions in this category wouldn't get good discussions here. Would the Physics SE be a likely good place to discuss this?

Comment: Well I suppose it might be. Currently it is a highly theoretical area still - I agree.